# I have some cranberry juice that developed some dark spots under the lid, is it still considered safe to drink?

Tags: spoilage

My mom had some cranberry juice that says best if used in 2018, and was wondering if it will do anything very bad to me, since it was sealed by a reputable manufacturer for this long, and never opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best used is a date after which the manufacturer says quality will likely be reduced, not a spoilage date.  Most items are safe after that date though some jurisdictions restrict selling after that date, but not using.  That said, you are two years beyond that date.  At two years, if in need and seals look good, no container damage, no discoloration, no gases, no off smells, no other signs of concern, then maybe it would be worth a risk.  Your item does not fit that criteria in my opinion.  The odds of it being bad are actually low, buy what need to you have to run that risk at all?

Answer (score 2):

Probably corrosion at pinholes in the internal coating ( lacquer type ) and not hazardous. However , I would not take the chance for a couple dollars can of juice.

Answer (score 1):

The best if used by date has to do with the sealed product, not once it is opened. This juice is very old and you should get rid of it.

Comment: we're not getting sick